# Background color of frame and shapes on paintComponent not working on netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Working on java, I have this problem, the shapes will not display on the frame. Also when changing the background of the frame it does not work. Can anyone please help me on this? Any help would be much appreciated. Here's my code:

```
public class PlayingWithShapes extends JFrame{

JMenuBar menuBar;
JMenu shapesMenu, colorsMenu;
JMenuItem rectangle, circle, square;
JMenuItem blue, red, green;

public PlayingWithShapes()
{
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    shapesMenu = new JMenu("Shapes");
    colorsMenu = new JMenu("Colors");
    rectangle = new JMenuItem("Rectangle");
    circle = new JMenuItem("Circle");
    square = new JMenuItem("Square");

    blue = new JMenuItem("blue");
    red = new JMenuItem("red");
    green = new JMenuItem("green");

    shapesMenu.add(rectangle);
    shapesMenu.add(circle);
    shapesMenu.add(square);

    colorsMenu.add(blue);
    colorsMenu.add(red);
    colorsMenu.add(green);

    menuBar.add(shapesMenu);
    menuBar.add(colorsMenu);

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    setBackground(Color.RED);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
    pack();

}
```

Paincomponent section--not displaying on the frame

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics shapes)
{
    super.paintComponents(shapes);
    //rectangle
    shapes.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    shapes.fillOval(250, 100, 150, 100);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    PlayingWithShapes shapes = new PlayingWithShapes();
    shapes.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> also when changing the background of the frame it does not work

Use `getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED)` instead

> I have this problem, the shapes will not display on the frame

`JFrame` doesn't have a `paintComponent` method, you can test this by using the `@Override` annotation...

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics shapes)
{
    // Oh look, it's paintComponent**s**, that should have raised
    // eyebrows
    super.paintComponents(shapes);
    //rectangle
    shapes.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    shapes.fillOval(250, 100, 150, 100);
}
```

Start by having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about painting in Swing.

General recommendations:

- Don't extend from `JFrame`, ever, it's not really doing you any favours
- Start by extending from something like `JPanel` instead and override its `paintComponent` method.  Then, add an instance of this panel to whatever container you like.

For example...

[image: Shapes]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class PlayingWithShapes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PlayingWithShapes();
    }

    public PlayingWithShapes() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu shapesMenu = new JMenu("Shapes");
                JMenu colorsMenu = new JMenu("Colors");
                JMenuItem rectangle = new JMenuItem("Rectangle");
                JMenuItem circle = new JMenuItem("Circle");
                JMenuItem square = new JMenuItem("Square");

                JMenuItem blue = new JMenuItem("blue");
                JMenuItem red = new JMenuItem("red");
                JMenuItem green = new JMenuItem("green");

                shapesMenu.add(rectangle);
                shapesMenu.add(circle);
                shapesMenu.add(square);

                colorsMenu.add(blue);
                colorsMenu.add(red);
                colorsMenu.add(green);

                menuBar.add(shapesMenu);
                menuBar.add(colorsMenu);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new ShapePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ShapePane extends JPanel {

        public ShapePane() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            g2d.fillOval(250, 100, 150, 100);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you nice information there Jframe does not have paintOmponent. Now working. I now this is off topic but what if I only want to display the oval shape after click the circle under the menubar? Lets say im inside the actionPerformed method.

Comment: Generally the way this gets done, is you have a `List` or array of `Shape`s, which you update on some "action" (like the menu item been clicked), you then call `repaint` on the "shape pane" and it iterates through the list/array and paints what ever's there. Have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for some more details

Comment: Can you give samples on this?